# Как отправлять сообщение с задержкой в телеграм боте?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

**Нужно что бы бот отправлял сообщение с задержкой в несколько секунд. Как это возможно сделать?(Не используя sleep())**

Использовал этот метод:
`t = threading.Timer(2.0, func, [chat_user_id])`

Есть метод попроще?
Использую telebot

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Что вы имеете в виду под словом "проще". Добавьте пояснение в сам вопрос, что вы ищете и чего хотите добиться

Comment: Указаным методом я создавал функции с одним сообщением, может есть метод который можно использовать все в одной функции(Отправка сообщений с задержкой)